# How to enable enableSwaggerCodegen to an existing jhipster project?

Tags: swagger, jhipster

I have a monolitic project where initially enableSwaggerCodegen = false. But now I want to add some custom API using the enableSwaggerCodegen functionality. 
How do I add that to my existing jhipster project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can set `"enableSwaggerCodegen": true` in `.yo-rc.json` and run command **`jhipster`** again and it will add files that are needed for **`SwaggerCodeGen`**

Comment: That worked as far as the swagger folder was generated. Under it I placed a custom api.yml file. How do I now generate the endpoints?